# Могут ли запросы выполняться одновременно?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

Есть две асинхронных функции:
task10() - получает список логинов пользователей для хабра за 10 секунд,
task2() - получает список логинов пользователей для гитхаба зы 2 секунды.

Поток выполнения программы доходит до task10 через 1 секунду после старта скрипта, до task2 - через 3 секунды. В результате эвент луп помещает их в некоторое временное "web_api_Хранилище" в таком порядке:

```
task10,
task2
```

Однако помещает их в [очередь асинхронных событий(callback queue)](https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*quyTIOs2hioCx1jRQ7-ojw.png) в таком порядке:

```
task2,
task10
```

Скажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что несмотря на то, что javascript язык однопоточный, "web_api_Хранилище" выполняет оба запроса на получение списков логинов одновременно и параллельно? И это связано с тем, что сам браузер не одопоточный и способен обработать таски одновременно.

Comment: что ты понимаешь под **выполнением запроса**?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _"web_api_Хранилище"_?

Comment: @Grundy под выполнением запроса я понимаю процесс получения логинов с сервера на клиент. 
"web_api_Хранилище" это в моём понимании какое-то дополнительное api, которое предоставляет среда(в данном случае браузер), и которое не является частью javascript. В реальности оно называется по-другому, скорее всего, но я не знаю как именно

Comment: В тегах есть event-loop, а понимания что это такое нет. Прочитайте как он устроен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, HTTP-запросы могут отправляться браузером параллельно.
Это зависит от реализации браузера, и наличия "свободного места" в его лимите одновременных подключений.
Порядок фактической отправки запросов, браузер может определять сам - независимо от порядка вызовов их отправки в скриптах (по крайней мере в Хроме, это фактически происходит. Я не знаю почему).

JS-коллбэки обрабатывающие ответ - всегда выполняются последовательно (синхронно), несмотря на то что они находятся в "асинхронной" очереди. Потому что выполнение JS однопоточное.

Порядок выполнения коллбэков в асинхронной очереди зависит от выполнения условий их вызова.
Например, если ответ на запрос отправленный вторым, придет раньше ответа на запрос отправленный первым - естественно, сначала будет вызван коллбэк листенера второго запроса (так как первый запрос еще в ожидании ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Потоки и количество соединений не связанны. В современных операционных системах есть `epoll` и подобные конструкции. В программе реализован вечный цикл, который выполняет функции яваскрипта. При выполнении запроса браузер его формирует и выполняет. Потом продолжает исполнять другие команды. При этом после каждой смотрит ответ от ядра выполнился там запрос или нет. Получив порцию данных в ответ цикл обрабатывает её и вновь дергает команды из очереди, снова прерывается на получение данных и так далее.

Если знакомы с си, то можете почитать про uvloop - это библиотека, которая телает то о чем вы говорите: несколько запросов одновременно.